# Quarkus Microservices - SmallRye

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I use the SmallRye Health extension in Quarkus.

The `/q/health-ui` is acutally only enabled in devmode.
How can i enable it in the runtime?

```
%runtime.quarkus.smallrye.health.ui.enable=true
```

Does not work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now: quarkus.smallrye-health.ui.always-include=true worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake on the profile name, it's not runtime but prod as default non test/dev profile.

Usage is similar to what you've already done :

```
%prod.quarkus.smallrye-health.ui.enable=true
```

### Edit

I saw it a bit late, but you also miss typed the param name, there is a `-` between smallrye and health, not a dot as you typed in your question

See [Quarkus Smallrye health extension configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health#quarkus-smallrye-health_quarkus.smallrye-health.ui.enable)

Comment: This does not work. The site was not found...
What shall i do jacouille